# IndexedDB transaction always throwing onabort from add() method in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, asynchronous, indexeddb

I just started experimenting with IndexedDB.  I copied an example and pared it down to a small HTML page:   Push a button; add a record; dump all the records to the console after the transaction completes.

It runs fine in IE11, but not on Chrome.

The request=transaction.objectstore("store").add({k:v})is always executing the request.onsuccess() method, but the transaction is always resolved with transaction.onabort() by Chrome.   Same with .put().

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    //--- globals 
    var db;

    // The initialization of our stuff in body.onload()
    function init() {
        var dbVersion = 1;

        //--- Try to delete any existing database
        var delRequest = indexedDB.deleteDatabase("notesDB");
        delRequest.onsuccess = function (de) {
            dbOpen(); // .... then open a new one
        };

        delRequest.onerror = function (de) {
            dbOpen(); // ... or open a new one if one doesn't exist to delete
        };

        function dbOpen () {
            var openRequest = indexedDB.open("notesDB", dbVersion);

            openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
                var ldb = e.target.result;
                console.log("running onupgradeneeded; always start with a fresh object store");
                if (ldb.objectStoreNames.contains("note")) {
                    ldb.deleteObjectStore("note");
                }
                if (!ldb.objectStoreNames.contains("note")) {
                    console.log("creating new note data store");
                    var objectStore = ldb.createObjectStore("note", { autoIncrement: true });
                    objectStore.createIndex("title", "title", { unique: false });
                }
            };

            openRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
                db = e.target.result;

                db.onerror = function (event) {
                    // Generic error handler for all errors targeted at this database
                    alert("Database error: " + event.target.errorCode);
                    console.dir(event.target);
                };
                console.log("Database opened; dump existing rows (shouldn't be any)");
                displayNotes();
            };

            openRequest.onerror = function (e) {
                console.log("Open error");
                console.log(e);
                console.dir(e);
            };
        }

        function displayNotes() {
            console.log("TODO - print something nice on the page");
            var tx = db.transaction("note", "readonly");
            tx.oncomplete = function (event) { console.log("read only cursor transaction complete"); }
            tx.onerror = function (event) { console.log("readonly transaction onerror"); }
            tx.onabort = function (event) { console.log("readonly transaction onabort"); }

            // --- iterate cursor
            console.log("---Start cursor dump---")
            var ds = tx.objectStore("note");
            ds.openCursor().onsuccess = function (event) {
                var cursor = event.target.result;
                if (cursor) {
                    console.log(cursor.key);
                    console.dir(cursor.value);
                    cursor.continue();
                }
                else {
                    console.log("---End cursor dump---");
                }
            };
        }


        document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("click", function (clickevent) {
            try {
                var transaction = db.transaction("note", "readwrite");
                transaction.oncomplete = function (event) {
                    console.log("Cursor dump in 'add' read/write transaction oncomplete");
                    displayNotes();
                    console.log("add transaction oncomplete done!");
                };
                transaction.onerror = function (event) {
                    console.log("add transaction onerror");
                };
                transaction.onabort = function (event) {
                    console.log("add transaction onabort");
                };

                var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("note");

                var request = objectStore.add({
                    title: "note header",
                    body: "this is random note body content " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
                });

                request.onsuccess = function (event) {
                    console.log("add request onsuccess");
                };
                request.onerror = function (event) {
                    console.log("add request onerror");
                    console.dir(event);
                };
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log('catchall exception');
                console.log(e);
                alert("bad things done");
            }

        });
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init()"> 
    <h1>IndexedDB simplest example</h1>
    <p>
        <button id="test">Push To Add Row To IndexedDB</button>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I clicked the button a bunch of times and it worked every time.

What error are you getting when it aborts? Look in `event.target.error` in the `onabort` handler to see. It could be a QuotaExceededError, which would mean that either you have very low hard drive space or you have a lot of data stored in Chrome for your domain. If that's the case, it's good you're running into it now, because you do need to gracefully handle this case, otherwise users will hit it and be confused.

Comment: What is the graceful way to handle this?   It is indeed a QuotaExceededError,.  How do you extend it?   When I ask using the method at [link]https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage#query it returns 0 of 0. `navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota ( 
    function(usedBytes, grantedBytes) {  
        console.log('we are using ', usedBytes, ' of ', grantedBytes, 'bytes');
    }, 
    function(e) { console.log('Error', e);  }
);`     same for *PersistentStorage method.

Comment: Getting 0,0 back from queryUsageAndQuota is very bizzare. Can you file a bug against Chrome via https://crbug.com and we'll try and figure out what's going on with your machine.

Also, are you testing against a server (e.g. http://localhost/...) rather than files (e.g. file:///...) ?